# What does API Stats mean in Facebook Developers site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am administering a Facebook App. When I open the App console, I come across two graphs:
1. Facebook Login.
2. API Stats.

Can somebody help me understand the meanings of these two term against the graph?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is number of users that logs in.
2. API stats is how many API calls your app is doing.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
My App API stats shows 8. But My App is not complete yet also nobody knows about my app. So these API calls are only because of my testing?

Comment: Yes, when you do testing you also do API calls